# Клиент шлет данные сам себе

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, udp

Так выглядит клиент

```
     public static void connect(String host, int port) {
            address = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
            try {
                channel = DatagramChannel.open();
                channel.configureBlocking(false);
                channel.bind(address);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка подключения");
            }
        }


        public static void run(Information information) {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
            // Answer answerr=new Answer();

            try {
                System.out.println(information.cmdtype);
                byte[] commandInBytes = commandSerializationManager.writeObject(information);
                byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(commandInBytes);
                channel.send(byteBuffer, address);
                byteBuffer.clear();

                byte[] answerInBytes = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                System.out.println("Запрос отправлен на сервер...");
                byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(answerInBytes);
                do {
                    try {
                        address = channel.receive(byteBuffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } while (address == null);
                System.out.println(address);
                Answer result = new Answer();
                result = responseSerializationManager.readObject(answerInBytes); '....
```

А вот код сервера:

```
     public static void connect(int port) {

           // address = new InetSocketAddress(port);
            try {
                socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(port);
                datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                datagramSocket.connect(socketAddress);
                Logger.login(Level.INFO,"Сервер начинает работу");
            } catch ( SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void run() throws Exception {
            while (true){

               DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                try {
                    System.out.println("1");
                    datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
                 //   Logger.login(Level.INFO,"Получен пакет");
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException socketTimeoutException) {
                    socketTimeoutException.printStackTrace();
                } ....
```

Я получаю `java.lang.ClassCastException: Information cannot be cast to Answer`
Происходит это потому, что клиент принимает отправленные им же данные, можно ли избежать этого?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, на клиенте стоило использовать `channel.connect()`, вместо `channel.bind()`